# Is macro_rules a regular macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to understand rust macro syntax. [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html) I read  that macro may be invoked generally in 3 flavours:

```
mymacro!(<tokens>);
mymacro![<tokens>];
mymacro!{<tokens>};
```

...and then I see an example macro definition also using macro (`macro_rules`), but the syntax doesn't conform to these rules:

```
macro_rules! name {<tokens>}
```

Is `name` a token and we have 4-th legal macro invocation form here or `macro_rules` is rather a keyword than just macro and uses special syntax not available for regular macros?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `macro_rules` is a special "directive". You can check the compiler syntax tree [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#macros-by-example).
The important part is:

```
Syntax
MacroRulesDefinition :
   macro_rules ! IDENTIFIER MacroRulesDef
```

You can see that it is the entry point of the macros syntax.

Comment: I don't know if directive is the correct word for this actually. So an edit is welcome to specify this.

Comment: The term I've seen commonly used is "compiler built-in"